# Hessian of inner product

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, analysis

Let $f:\mathbb R^n \rightarrow \mathbb R^n$ be a $C^2$ functions and consider the function

$h:\mathbb R^n \rightarrow \mathbb R$ given by
$$h(x):=\langle f(x),f(x) \rangle.$$

I am wondering whether it is possible to say what the Hessian $(D^2h)(x)$ is?

If $f$ was scalar it would be $2(f(x)f''(x)+f'(x)^2)$ but what happens in general?

Comment: Just compute it. You only need the linearity of the derivative and the product rule. It is the matrix with entries $2\langle D_j f,D_if\rangle+2\langle f,D_jD_i f\rangle$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$Hess(f)=\pmatrix{{\partial^2\over{\partial x_ix_j}}h}$

${\partial h\over{\partial x_i}}=$

$2\langle {\partial f(x)\over{\partial x_i}},f(x)\rangle$

${\partial^2 h\over{\partial x_j\partial x_i}}=$

$2(\langle {\partial^2 f(x)\over{\partial x_j\partial x_i}},f(x)\rangle+\langle {\partial f(x)\over{\partial x_i}},{\partial f(x)\over{\partial x_j}}\rangle)$